# Problemas ao adquirir dados de um Label em JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, label

Boa tarde, estou iniciando um exemplo simples para a aquisição de dados de um Label em JavaFX, porém estou com dificuldades, a maioria das fontes me indicavam a realizar da seguinte forma:

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

@FXML
private Label name;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    BorderPane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("RootLayout.fxml"));
    AnchorPane demo = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Demo.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    root.setCenter(demo);
    name.getText();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Porém, quando executo o programa o seguinte erro acontece e não consigo achar a causa do mesmo:

[imgur[][1] http://erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOsWa.png)

Já adicionei corretamente a classe controladora e o id que declarei no controller no scene builder, segue o código FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainApp">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="name" layoutX="241.0" layoutY="133.0" text="Label">
         <font>
            <Font size="29.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 1):

O erro Unknow Source quer dizer que ele não conseguiu encontrar o fxml que você especificou, verifique o nome do arquivo.